# iOS printing controller use async in renderer.numberOfPages

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, printing

I'm currently using direct print functionality in my app with `UIPrintInteractionController.print(to: printer)` and I have to asynchronously format my document before send it to printer using `UIPrinterPageRenderer.paperRect` data.

But this value is only available during `print` method execution.

I have a custom implementation of `UIPrinterPageRenderer` that override `numberOfPages` getter (this getter is called inside of `print` method and gives an initialized `paperRect` value).

So I can format my document in this getter, but I have to format my document asynchronously, and I'm stuck here...

Here is my current code:

```swift
public class PrintManager : UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate {
    private var channel: FlutterMethodChannel?
    private var renderer: CustomPrintPageRenderer?

    // Some other methods...

    // Print method called after user interaction
    func print(_ name: String, withPrinter printer: UIPrinter) {
        let controller = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
        controller.delegate = self

        let printInfo = UIPrintInfo.printInfo()
        printInfo.jobName = name
        printInfo.outputType = .general
        controller.printInfo = printInfo

        renderer = CustomPrintPageRenderer(channel)
        controller.renderer = renderer

        controller.print(to: printer, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }

    // Print completion handler
    func completionHandler(printController _: UIPrintInteractionController, completed: Bool, error: Error?) {
        if !completed, error != nil {
            print("Unable to print", error?.localizedDescription ?? "unknown error")
        }
        renderer = nil
    }
}
```

```swift
class CustomPrintPageRenderer : UIPrintPageRenderer {
    private var channel: FlutterMethodChannel?
    private var pdfDocument: CGPDFDocument?

    init(_ channel: FlutterMethodChannel?) {
        super.init()
        self.channel = channel
        pdfDocument = nil
    }

    // Parse pdfDocument data
    func setDocument(_ data: Data?) {
        let bytesPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: data?.count ?? 0)
        data?.copyBytes(to: bytesPointer, count: data?.count ?? 0)
        let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(dataInfo: nil, data: bytesPointer, size: data?.count ?? 0, releaseData: dataProviderReleaseDataCallback)
        pdfDocument = CGPDFDocument(dataProvider!)
    }

    // This method is called by the UIPrintInteractionController
    override func drawPage(at pageIndex: Int, in _: CGRect) {
        let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        let page = pdfDocument?.page(at: pageIndex + 1)
        ctx?.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        ctx?.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: -paperRect.size.height)
        ctx?.drawPDFPage(page!)
    }   

    // This getter is called by the UIPrintInteractionController
    override var numberOfPages: Int {
        let formatData = [
            "width": NSNumber(value: Double(paperRect.size.width)),
            "height": NSNumber(value: Double(paperRect.size.height)),
            //...
        ];

        // This method is asynchronous and call a completion handler when it finishes
        channel?.invokeMethod("getDocument", arguments: formatData) {(data: Any?) in 
            // In this completion handler I have my document data
            if let object = data as? FlutterStandardTypedData {
                self.setDocument(object.data)
            }
        }

        // pdfDocument must be initialized here
        let pages = pdfDocument?.nuberOfPages ?? 0

        return pages
    }
}
```

Actually this code doesn't work because `pdfDocument` is initialized too late.

So my question is: **Is there a way to wait the call of the completion handler of `channel?.invokeMethod()`?**

I tried to use `DispatchSemaphore` but as the print is done in the main thread it end with a freezing app (and my completion handler is not called).

After some tests, it seems that `controller.print()` cannot be called outside main thread.

Comment: did you find a solution? i have a similar problem, that i have some asynchronous calculations in the numberOfPages method

Comment: I initially needed this functionality for a Flutter printing plugin, it has been added recently, if it helps, you can have a look at: https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf/blob/b49c44970908c0a5448d732201000d67acb71853/printing/ios/Classes/PageRenderer.swift